# set background image through function or variable

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to change the background image of a div depending on various circumstances in a React component but first I need to figure out if it's possible to set the background image through a variable or a function, and it doesn't seem possible. For example, with a variable, something like this pseudo code doesn't seem to work

```
render: function(){
var myvariable = "url('http://localhost:8080/assets/myimage.jpg')"
return (
    <div style={{ "backgroundImage": { myvariable }, "width": "300px"}}</div>
     )
}
```

I also tried to call a function from the inline styles, but the compiler objected toe `.` in `this.setBackgroundImage`

```
 setBackgroundImage: function(){
     return "url('http://localhost:8080/assets/myimage.jpg')"
 },
 render: function(){

    return (
        <div style={{ "backgroundImage": { this.setBackgroundImage }, "width": "300px"}}</div>
         )
    }
```

Question: is it possible to call a function or use a variable in inline styles in React and, if not, how could I achieve what I'm attempting to do (i.e. rotate background images for a div)?

Note, the div has to have other styles on it (width, height etc), not just the background image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is to compose styles like:

```
var divStyle = {
  backgroundImage: 'url(' + imgUrl + ')',
  width: '300px'
};
```

And then use them inline:

```
return (
  <div style={divStyle}></div>
)
```

[React Inline Styles](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html)

Comment: I've seen a similar answer to that but I have multiple styles that need to be applied(there's a note about that in the OP). How can I add other styles to the divStyle object? Everything I try throws an illegal token error or unexpected identifier.

Comment: I'll accept your answer based on its reference to the authority but for some reason it's only working for me when I do it inline.